# netty threads distribution

Tags: netty

A `Channel` is attached to a single `EventLoop` durring `Channel.Unsafe#register`. The registration is distributed by a modulo operation in `EventExecutorGroup#next`. A `ChannelHandlerContext` is bound to a single thread -- often the same thread as the `Channel`.

Channels may be unevenly deregistered or the workload is unevenly distributed between these channels. By chance it is possible to have a single thread handling the complete workload.

Is there a pattern to prevent this case or is this an unavoidable structural problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force to use just one Thread if you construct the NioEventLoopGroup with the argument 1 . Other then that I think we could only improve it by calculate how many channels are on an EventLoop and choose the next based on this. But even this may not be a good way as some Channel may do more heavy work then the others.

Comment: So it is a structural trait and the thread model has to be rewritten to prevent excessive load on a single thread bound to multiple channels. I'll test if individual dispatching to others may act as a workaround.

Should I file an issue?